# Must a button control be added as a property in the Interface?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new to Objective C and there are a few basic things that I do not yet understand from the tutorials and books I've looked at.  For this question I am confused about whether a button needs to be connected to a property in the Interface as well as being connected to the IBAction method.

Seems like a simple question that might help others.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hook up items in interface builder to IBOutlets only if you need to operate on them in the view controller. For instance, if you wanted to change the button's title text to be localized on load, then you would hook it up. If all you want to do is respond to a specific action on the button (touch up inside for instance), then you only need to hook up the IBAction portion. The short answer is that you are not required to hook up the IBOutlet.